# make public class between Today extension and ViewController in app

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create Today app extension. I want to have one UIViewController for loading all data to app and use the same variables in this UIViewController for Today Extension and App. 
For Example: I have UILabel for TodayAppExtension and for app and I want to connect Label text like:
my_label.text = "hello"
to both UILabels ... I tried make public class for do it like example:

THIS IS CLASS FOR BOTH  VIEWCONTROLLERS

> import UIKit
>
> public class AppDataViewController: UIViewController {
>
> ```
> @IBOutlet public var pacificLabel: UILabel!
>
> override public func viewDidLoad() {
>     super.viewDidLoad()
> }
>
> override public func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
>     super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
>     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
> }
>
>
> public func updateClocks() {
>     var time: NSDate = NSDate()
>     println("Time: \(time)")
>
>     var timeString : NSString = "Time: \(time)"
>
>     let formatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter();
>     var timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
>     formatter.timeZone = timeZone
>     formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
>     println("UTC Time: \(formatter.stringFromDate(time))")
>
>     timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "US/Pacific")
>     formatter.timeZone = timeZone
>     formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
>     println("PST Time: \(formatter.stringFromDate(time))")
>     self.pacificLabel.text = formatter.stringFromDate(time)
>
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

How can I access to this self.pacificLabel.text from StoryBoard from App and StoryBoard from Extension ? 
Always when I'm trying to call function updateClock() from ViewController I get this:

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never created pacificLabel.

In your

```
override public func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

You need to create a UILabel object.

The error you're getting is because you declared it as an optional that WILL exist when you use it. So you dont need to unwrap it. As such it expected pacificLabel to exist, which it didn't at the time you 'unwrapped it'.

Create the UILabel object inside viewDidLoad and it will work.

If the issue is that you have this label existing in your storyboard, you need to control-drag that object from the view class (the view in the storyboard) to the script to create a reference to that object.

[image: Drag from view class]

Comment: I've created an label 
"@IBOutlet public var pacificLabel: UILabel!"
in that file AppDataViewController.swift (see the code in my post)

Comment: Then please update your question with the full error message. You might have a broken link between the outlet and the view. What is it saying is nil?